# Save button does not work in fronend editor of Joomla after upgrading to 3.8.2

Tags: joomla

After upgrading to Joomla 3.8.2 from 3.6, users, be it super user, author or editor, cannot save anything via Front end editor on articles.
After opening the editor in an article, it opens as before and everything works as before in the editor until the user clicks on save button. Instead of saving and closing the article the page refreshes and goes back to editor with all the new changes still there, but nothing has been saved. The user can only click on cancel button and all the new changes will be deleted, then article editor will be closed.

I tried to make sure users have all the permissions under

> Global Config >>> Article manager
>
> Components >>> JCE >>> Profiles

Text Filters are all set to allow any script...

Changes on the same article can be made in back end with the same user.
Different editors such as JCE, ARK, CodeMirror and TinyEditor have been tried. No difference.
Actually this happens right after upgrading to 3.8.2 without manually making any changes in the configurations or editor.

It looks like it is a JavaScript conflict between save button and a component of another plugin. Any ideas or clues how this problem can be solved?

Here are some basic Info on my platform:

PHP 5.6.31

MySQL 5.5.57

Joomla! 3.8.2 Stable

Joomla Platform 13.1.0 Stable

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On several sites, I have had a conflict with multiple things loading Google recaptcha.  Joomla recently added where the recaptcha can be required in frontend editing, but it doesn't appear when multiple instances of recaptcha are being loaded.  (I have had Joomla user, Engagebox, RSForms, etc also load).  
Disabling recaptcha from frontend editing fixed it for me.
https://www.yellowwebmonkey.com/developer-blog/item/error-message-empty-solution-not-allowed

Comment: I had deactivated the captcha plugin to test if this conflicts and it led to fatal error after hitting the save button. But after I set it to "Allow Captcha on Submit" to NONE as you suggested, it fixed the save button issue, however it affects the captcha functionality. I try to mirror this Joomla system to be able to test different approaches without being afraid of affecting the production environment. Thanks for your input YellowWebMonkey!